# Access virtual serial port outside Arduino IDE

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ableton-live

I have a [LighBlue Bean](http://punchthrough.com/bean/) which is an Arduino compatible Bluetooth LE microcontroller. I'm trying to access its virtual serial port outside the Arduino IDE. I can see the serial data in the Arduino Serial Monitor and also in screen using the terminal command;

```
screen /tmp/tty.LightBlue-Bean 57600
```

However, the serial port doesn't show up in other apps in OS X such as [Hairless MIDI to Serial Bridge](http://projectgus.github.io/hairless-midiserial/) or Ableton.

In terminal, the following command;

```
ls /dev/tty.*
```

does not list the Beans virtual serial port which is /tmp/tty.LightBlue-Bean. The following command does show it;

```
ls /tmp/tty.*
```

However, only serial ports starting /dev/ show up in other apps.

How can I make the virtual serial port of the LightBlue Bean visible in other apps so I can send serial data to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to symlink the port to `/dev` like that

```
ln -s /tmp/tty.LightBlue-Bean /dev/tty.LightBlue-Bean
```

You can also change the name to something simplier if you want.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks @ladislas. That does work and allows me to access the serial port via /dev but for some reason, it doesn't show up in programs like Ableton as a serial port. Is it because it's a virtual serial port?